# Convert IPv6 to hex notation

Tags: python, hex, ubuntu-14.04, ipv6

My interface is setup:

```
iface eth1 inet6 static
    address 0:0:0:0:0:ffff:6464:640a
    netmask 64
```

but when running `ifconfig eth1` you see the following configuration:

```
eth1  inet6 addr: 100.100.100.10/64 Scope:Global
```

This is because `0:0:0:0:0:ffff:6464:640a` translates into `100.100.100.10/64`.

I have a code in python that retreives the IP Addresses from each interface:

```
import netifaces
interface_info = netifaces.ifaddresses('eth1')

if netifaces.AF_INET6 in interface_info:
   return interface_info[netifaces.AF_INET][0]['addr']
```

The above code returns the IPv6 of eth1 as `::ffff:100.100.100.10`.
For my code, I need that the IPv6 will be the original hex notation, i.e., `::ffff:6464:640a` and not `::ffff:100.100.100.10`.
Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: You could detect IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses and print them as pure IPv6 addresses. However, I wonder *why* you need that? IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses are standard.

Comment: Watch out: those mapped addresses are not meant to be used on networks! They are meant to represent IPv4 addresses in IPv6-only software. Configuring them on actual interfaces will give very unpredictable results.

Comment: According to the Standards Track _[RFC 5952, A Recommendation for IPv6 Address Text Representation](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952)_, the mixed hex and dotted decimal format is correct for the IPv4-mapped addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`ipaddress` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html):

```
In [54]: import ipaddress

In [55]: addr = '::ffff:100.100.100.10'

In [59]: ipaddress.ip_address(addr)
Out[59]: IPv6Address('::ffff:6464:640a')

In [60]: str(ipaddress.ip_address(addr))
Out[60]: '::ffff:6464:640a'
```

Comment: Excellent! Just what I was looking for.